# layering in flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using a basic loader and urlRequest to load in swf's on my flash page. So I have some art on my main swf that I want to appear on top of the loaded swf's. I recently have found out that the loaded swf's load ontop of everything on the main swf. Can someone tell me how you go about putting the loaded swf's in the background, on a specific layer, or something like that? I tried searching the internet but to be honest "layering in flash" didnt turn up anything and im not really sure what else to search for. I can post my code if needed but its really simple stuff, all I got is loading different swf's with buttons, thats it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was researching on the internet a bit more and found the addChildAt . I just added a 0 like this addChildAt(somewhere, 0);

this allowed me to position the swf's on the bottom of everything!
heres were found the code snippet, its a comment at the bottom of the page.

http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=24905

Comment: I guess you mean to say addChildAt(someClip, someLayer);